# Default Admin Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am developing a rest API with more than 400 endpoints with spring  boot. I want to make  configuration to automatically give all users who have ADMIN Role, access to all end point without adding *@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")* on each specific endpoint.

How is to possible to make a configuration in the method below to achieve this goal?

```
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                http.cors();
                http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(
                "/authenticate",
                "/postulant/nouveau",
                "/postulant/all",
                "/modifierPostulant/{id}",
                "/plannificationConcours/all",                
                "/v2/api-docs",
                "/swagger-resources",
                "/swagger-resources/**",
                "/configuration/ui",
                "/configuration/security",
                "/swagger-ui.html",
                "/webjars/**",
                "/v3/api-docs/**",
                "/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpHeaders.ALLOW).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

Comment: Where it first says `permitAll`, put `hasRole("ADMIN")` instead.. if those are the paths which should be protected.

Comment: You are already allowing access for admin with `.anyRequest().authenticated()`. You have nothing to do.

Comment: I have more than 400 path, i want to give ADMIN Full access to all of them. i want to save time instead of making the configuration in each endpoint.

Comment: @GirbsonBIJOU did u find solution for this?